# HTML5 Frame by frame animation (multiple images)

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

I've been losing my mind over this. I spent 3 hours trying different methods and finding a solution online, and I still haven't fixed it.
I have two separate images(not a spritesheet) and they need to be displayed one after the other, as an animation, infinitely. Here's is my latest code:

```
var canvas, context, imageOne, imageTwo, animation;    

function init(){
  canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
  context = canvas.getContext("2d");

  canvas.width = window.innerWidth;
  canvas.height = window.innerHeight;

  imageOne = new Image();
  imageTwo = new Image();

  imageOne.src = "catone.png";
  imageTwo.src = "cattwo.png";

  // Just to make sure both images are loaded
  setTimeout(function() { requestAnimationFrame(main);}, 3000);
}

function main(){

  animation = {

    clearCanvas: function(){
      context.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
    },

    renderImageOne: function(){
      context.drawImage(imageOne, 100, 100);
    },

    renderImageTwo: function(){
      context.drawImage(imageTwo, 100, 100);
    }

  };

  animation.renderImageOne();

  // I also tried calling animation.clearCanvas();
  context.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);

  animation.renderImageTwo();

  // I put this here to confirm that the browser has entered the function, and that it hasn't stopped after animation.renderImageTwo();
  console.log("cats");
  requestAnimationFrame(main);
}

init();
```

But the problem is that the only one image is displayed, and it's not moving. I can't see any errors or warnings in the console. I'm also sure HTML and JavaScript are connected properly and the images are in the right path. So in any case, only the image in the first function is displayed. Example: animation.renderImageOne(); displays catone, but if I replace it with animation.renderImageTwo(); it displays cattwo.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is here:

```
  animation.renderImageOne();

  // I also tried calling animation.clearCanvas();
  context.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);

  animation.renderImageTwo();
```

Is it's drawing the first image, clearing the canvas, then drawing the second image, then after all that it draws to the screen. Leaving you with only seeing the second image. You will need a variable that alternates values, and use that to determine which picture you should draw:

```
var canvas, context, imageOne, imageTwo, animation;   
var imageToDraw = "one";
```

And then:

```
function main() {

  ...

  if(imageToDraw == "one") {
      animation.renderImageOne();
      imageToDraw = "two";
  }
  else if(imageToDraw == "two") {
      animation.renderImageTwo();
      imageToDraw = "one";
  }

  ...
}
```

*Note:* You don't need to define `animation` inside `main()`, you can move it into global scope. That way you don't redefine it each time you call `main()`.

Comment: Also I'm wondering if the use of strings is the most efficient way to set the "alternator" but upvote anyway :-)

Comment: @Kaiido I was thinking it just might be easier to read that way, I see your point, it might be a better idea to use a Boolean. Although it does open the opportunity to use more than two images.

Comment: yes indeed, in the case you've got a lot of images to alternate, it would be better to use an array and an increasing variable, my boolean in the comment was only for this particular 2 states switch. But I see your point of readibility, and I think it's what fits the best for OP.